# lambda capture error with gcc, compiles with clang

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following program does not compile with g++ 10.1.0

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int N>
struct A {
  constexpr static unsigned int i = N;
};

template <class U>
void f()
{
  constexpr unsigned int i = U::i;
  auto lambda = [&]() {
    if constexpr (i > 2) {
      std::cout << "i > 2" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "i <= 2" << std::endl;
    }
  };
  lambda();
}

int main()
{
  f<A<1>>();
  f<A<3>>();
  
  return 0;
}
```

With

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -o test test.cpp
```

the error is:

```
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:13:24: error: lambda capture of ‘i’ is not a constant expression
   13 |     if constexpr (i > 2) {
```

However, the same code compiles fine with clang++ 11.1.0 and produces the expected result.

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Might be relevant: [lambda capture breaks constexpr-ness of non-static const constexpr member call on non-constexpr value/variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82643). Note it compiles with gcc10.2

Comment: Does [this](https://twitter.com/TartanLlama/status/1283816537778982914) answer your question? xD

Comment: "_Which compiler is correct?_" type of questions _almost_ always require the "language-lawyer" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would **not need to capture it at all**: [`A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable: has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been initialized with a constant expression, or is constexpr and has no mutable members.`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

This also works in GCC:

```
auto lambda = []() {
    if constexpr (i > 2) {
      std::cout << "i > 2" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "i <= 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[Try it here.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9UTT4ciyQmh5ksdf)